# Can we do web automation without using selenium/ QTP etc?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ui-automation, webautomation

Can we do web automation without using selenium/ QTP etc? I think "No", but just to clarify the answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, **yes** we can automate the web application without using selenium/QTP. Nowadays, there are lot of tools available in the market which can automate the web application. Some of them are mentioned below.

1. **Katalon Studio**. Katalon Studio is a powerful automation tool set for web and mobile app testing. It is a free yet feature-packed solution that can be applied to overcome common challenges such as wait-time, pop-up and iframe in web UI test automation. Reference: https://www.katalon.com/katalon-studio/
2. **Sahi** is an automation and testing tool for web applications coming in an open-source.Sahi Open-source is written in Java and JavaScript and hosted on SourceForge since October 2005. It is released under an Apache License 2.0 Open Source License and its current version is 5.1 (published on October 5, 2016). Sahi Pro is currently in version 6.3.2 and is hosted on the Sahi Pro Website.
   Reference: http://sahipro.com
3. **Ghost Inspector** is an automated UI testing and monitoring tool. It allows you to record yourself performing actions on your website within your browser, then sync them to the Ghost Inspector service and run them continuously as a regression test. Reference: https://ghostinspector.com

and there are many more. Please let me know if there are any issues.

Thanks,

Krishna